# How to convert binary audio stream back to voice

Tags: websocket, webrtc, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I have this function that converts the microphone stream into binary code and send it to a server via web socket:

```
function WSAudioStream (source, socket, audioContext) {        
    this.ctx = audioContext;
    var self = this;
    var bufferLen = 4096;
    this.context = source.context;
    this.node = (this.context.createScriptProcessor ||
                 this.context.createJavaScriptNode).call(this.context, bufferLen, 2, 2);

    this.node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
      var sample = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      socket.send(sample);
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert the same sample stream that I send, back to voice and play it through the speakers.

I have tried to add the following code inside the onaudioprocess function, after the socket.send(sample) line:

```
var node = self.ctx.createBufferSource(0);
node.buffer = buffer;
node.connect(self.ctx.destination);
node.start(0);
```

But this didn't work.

Please advise What should be done for converting this stream back to voice?

Comment: Manipulating PCM data in JS and sending it raw is wrong on so many levels. It's not even a WebRTC. Use the PeerConnection API instead.

Comment: @Velkan I am aware to some of the issues related to sending raw data this way, but since I need to stream voice between JAVA server and a client, I am not sure that PeerConnection is possible in this scenario...

Comment: Are there problems with using PeerConnection in Java language?